# Failed to connect to localhost port 8000: Connection refused in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cmd, localhost

I'm trying to connect to the HTTP server in node.js.
I've spent my whole day searching online to solve my issue but unfortunately, it is of no use.

This is a simple code I wrote taking reference from official Node.js [documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-create-a-HTTP-server/).

**Index.js**

```
const http = require('http');

const requestListener = function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('Hello, World!');
}

const server = http.createServer(requestListener);
server.listen(8080);
```

**The code I am running inside CMD terminal**

```
curl localhost:8080
```

This returns the following error:
[image]

I know this questions have been asked a thousands time in stack overflow but none fixed my issue. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Not the downvoter but the issue is pretty obvious

Comment: Changed my edits @GuerricP.. :) But the issue is still the same..

Comment: Please add your nodejs logs

Comment: Please add your nodejs logs and the output of `netstat -a -b`. You should see something like `TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           DESKTOP-MOD2A4T:0      LISTENING
 [node.exe]`

Comment: Hello @GuerricP Here's my netstat screenshot. https://imgur.com/a/MbtGz73

Comment: OK this is pretty unreadable. Can you try with PowerShell: `Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 8080).OwningProcess` also don't forget to add what's being displayed by the Node.js console when you start the server. If the PowerShell command returns something in the  `Id` column, check in your task manager what is the corresponding process

Comment: @GuerricP https://imgur.com/a/NxXbTj1

Comment: @PrabinParajuli ok now what shows when you execute the server?

Comment: It shows these errors:

`internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:984
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\prabi\app\server'
[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:981:15)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:27)[39m
[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)[39m
[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47[39m {
  code: [32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'[39m,
  requireStack: []
}`

Answer (score 0):

In you code you are listening to port 8080 but from commandline you are trying 8000. Make sure you are using correct port and ensure its not in use.

Comment: Hey Rajat,
Updated my code. Sorry typo mistake. It gives the same error even if I try to connect with  the port 3000. :(

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to execute `C:\Users\prabi\app\server.js` when the real file is `C:\Users\prabi\app\index.js` so verify the `start` script in `package.json` and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Fire up another terminal and run the command:

> node index.js

Then go back to your previous terminal window/tab and run *curl localhost:8080* again. Should work.

The problem is that your code has been written well, but you aren't executing it at all. So if you don't run your node code, your http server cannot listen at the 8080 port in the first place.

Comment: What is the output in terminal when you run
node index.js ?

Comment: Please understand what I'm trying to say.
You have to run **node index.js**
And then run **curl localhost** in a _seperate terminal_